# ListView doesn't stop on finger up?

Tags: android, scroll, android-listview

I have a listView which defined like this in xml:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_x="4dp"
        android:layout_y="183dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </ListView>
```

Everything's just fine, but in a strange way if user wants to scroll the list down to see other items and gets his finger up list turns back to top ? It's just not stopping where user scrolled... Why could it be happening?
Thanks for help in advance...

Comment: your xml code is working fine, there is no problem in above code, you should look elsewhere in your code.

Comment: where else can the problem be at? on my custom listView adapter?

Comment: may be, I have tested above code its working...you should post some more code.

Comment: @yahya: you should answer your own question instead of updating your question.You can also accept your own answer to increase your accept ratio and for reference of others having same issue as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line, somehow, has solved my problem :

```
android:layout_marginBottom = "60dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"        
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:enabled="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: But I think,that are the only tags which creates problem.

Comment: I tried also change the layout into a relative and put layout_marginTop="150dp" but didn't solve my problem...

Comment: layout_marginTop is just to set the margin from your view on top side and that will just leave the space of 150dp as you specified so.I don't think,i can be the cause of your problem.Are you using this listview inside LinearLayout?

Comment: I've got a relativeLayout and inside of it there's another one which contains this listView

Comment: ok..But I don't think,relative layout is the cause of your problem.Sorry,I can't help you more.I have no idea where can be the problem else than those two lines.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you shouldn't use match_parent for height.

Comment: i tried fill_parent and wrap_content as well, but still same :/

Comment: As match_parent is exactly the same as fill_parent, that's to be expected.